# Why sklearn returns the accuracy and weighted-average recall the same value in binary classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, metrics

My problem is a binary classification where I use the following code to get the `accuracy` and `weighted average recall`.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf=RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 0, class_weight="balanced")

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=10, scoring = ('accuracy', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_weighted', 'f1_weighted'))
```

I noted that the values of `accuracy` and `weighted average recall` are equal. However, as I understand these two metrics capture two different aspects and thus, I am not clear why they are exactly equal.

I found a post that have similar question: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Multiclass_classification_micro_weighted_recall_equals_accuracy. However, I did not found the answers of that post useful.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: can you add your output and an idea of the dataframe?

Comment: @PV8 Thank you for the comment, if I eloborated my question it is exactly similar to this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350849/recall-equals-to-accuracy-but-different-to-precision :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accuracy is:

```
TP + TN / (P+ N)
```

So let's assume you have 50 positive classes and 50 negative, and somehow this is prediction 25 correct of your positive classes and 25 correct of your negativ classes, then:

```
25 + 25 / (50+50) = 0.5
```

Weighted average recall:
First recall: `TP/P = 25/50 = 0.5`

Weighted recall:

```
(recall_posivite*number_positve)+(recall_negative*number_negative)/(number_positive + number_negativ) = 0.5*50+0.5*50/(50+50) = 50/100 = 0.5
```

I hope this helps to understand that it can happen!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to work through the equations. However, I could not identify why they were equal. It would be great if you could show me throgh a simple example. My question is in detail similar to this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350849/recall-equals-to-accuracy-but-different-to-precision Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you :)